# Making a screenshot using Xlib and Cairo libs [fail]

Tags: png, screenshot, x11, cairo, xlib

I'm trying to make a screenshot using **Xlib** and **Cairo**, however I'm not sure to do it the good way, "stride" is really confusing me.

Here's the code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <cairo.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xutil.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    int x, y;

    Display *disp;
    Window root;
    XWindowAttributes watts;
    XImage *image;
    cairo_surface_t *surface;
    unsigned int width;
    unsigned int height;
    int stride;

    disp = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    root = DefaultRootWindow(disp);
    XGetWindowAttributes(disp, root, &watts);
    width = watts.width;
    height = watts.height;

    image = XGetImage(disp, root, watts.x, watts.y, width, height, AllPlanes, ZPixmap);
    stride = cairo_format_stride_for_width(CAIRO_FORMAT_RGB24, width);
    unsigned char *data = malloc(width * height * 3);

    for (y = 0; y < height; ++y)
        for (x = 0; x < width; ++x) {

            unsigned long pixel = XGetPixel(image, x, y);

            unsigned char red = (image->red_mask & pixel);
            unsigned char green = (image->green_mask & pixel) >> 8;
            unsigned char blue = (image->blue_mask & pixel) >> 16;

            data[(y * width + x) * 3] = red;
            data[(y * width + x) * 3 + 1] = green;
            data[(y * width + x) * 3 + 2] = blue;
        }


    surface = cairo_image_surface_create_for_data(
            data,
            CAIRO_FORMAT_RGB24,
            width, height,
            stride);

    cairo_surface_write_to_png(
            surface,
            "test.png");


    cairo_surface_destroy(surface);
    free(data);

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

When I compile and run the program, everything seems to work just fine. However here's the resulting image :

[image: quite a mess]

quite a mess right ?..
**What am I possibly doing wrong ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TFM:

```
CAIRO_FORMAT_RGB24
    each pixel is a 32-bit quantity, with the upper 8 bits unused
```

TFM:

```
stride = cairo_format_stride_for_width (format, width);
data = malloc (stride * height);
```

Hence, the correct index calculation is

```
data[y * stride + x * 4 + 0] = blue;
data[y * stride + x * 4 + 1] = green;
data[y * stride + x * 4 + 2] = red;    /* yes, in this order */
```

Also, masks are taken from the image and shifts are hard-coded, which makes absolutely no sense. Calculate the shifts from the masks.

Comment: You are supposed to use different index calculations because the pixel size is 32 bits and not 24. See update.

Comment: That's because you are not using the correct shifts, and/or using a wrong order of R, G and B.

Comment: You should calculate the correct pointer, cast it to uint32_t* and do *p = red << 16 | green << 8 | blue;. That way your code will also work correctly on big-endian machines.

Answer (score 7):

Instead of doing all this complicated magic, let cairo do it for you:

```
#include <cairo.h>
#include <cairo-xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Display *disp;
    Window root;
    cairo_surface_t *surface;
    int scr;

    disp = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    scr = DefaultScreen(disp);
    root = DefaultRootWindow(disp);

    surface = cairo_xlib_surface_create(disp, root, DefaultVisual(disp, scr),
            DisplayWidth(disp, scr), DisplayHeight(disp, scr));
    cairo_surface_write_to_png(
            surface,
            "test.png");
    cairo_surface_destroy(surface);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for this answer, I plan to change my code to this, seems to be a little easier.

Comment: Hi @Uli. I find very useful your comment for a concept proof that I'm deploying. Could you please indicate me the libraries that I need in order to link to your code and get an executable? Thanks

Comment: Use pkg-config: pkg-config --libs --cflags cairo x11