# Screen capture program in C or C++ and Linux

Tags: c++, c, screenshot

I am looking for a program to capture screen in Linux using C or Cpp. can someone help with giving a skeleton structure or program what can help me.

Thanks and Regards.

Comment: Read manual for libX11: you can grab display and save its content into file.

Comment: Take a code from `xwd` sources: you need only 1-2 pages of code!

Answer (score 2):

[How to capture screen with ffmpeg:](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/How%20to%20grab%20the%20desktop%20%28screen%29%20with%20FFmpeg)

> Use the x11grab device:
>
> ffmpeg -f x11grab -r 25 -s 1024x768 -i :0.0+100,200 output.flv
>
> This will grab the image from desktop, starting with the upper-left
>   corner at (x=100, y=200) with the width and height of 1024x768.
>
> If you need audio too, you can use alsa like this:
>
> ffmpeg -f x11grab -r 25 -s 1024x768 -i :0.0+100,200 -f alsa -ac 2 -i
>   pulse output.flv

So you can simply place this in `capture.sh` and run it from your code:

```
#include <cstdlib>

int main(){ std::system("./capture.sh"); }
```

If you have to do it without calling external utilities, you can use [libffmpeg directly.](http://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html)

Comment: That looks good. I tried using external libraries but couldnt find a perfect program. are there any sample programs that use third party api to capture screen shot?

Comment: It worked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15507788/making-a-screenshot-using-xlib-and-cairo-libs-fail