# Seg fault in cairo when using some static libraries

Tags: c++, c, linker, cairo, xlib

I have the following routine for taking a screenshot:

```
void take_screenshot(const std::string & file_name)
{
  Display *disp;
  Window root;
  cairo_surface_t *surface;
  int scr;

  disp = XOpenDisplay(nullptr);
  scr = DefaultScreen(disp);
  root = DefaultRootWindow(disp);

  surface = cairo_xlib_surface_create(disp, root, DefaultVisual(disp, scr),
                      DisplayWidth(disp, scr), 
                      DisplayHeight(disp, scr));
  cairo_surface_write_to_png(surface, file_name.c_str()); // <-- here is the seg fault
  cairo_surface_destroy(surface);
}
```

This routine was taken from the answer of https://stackoverflow.com/users/436275/uli-schlachter to this question [Making a screenshot using Xlib and Cairo libs [fail]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15507788/making-a-screenshot-using-xlib-and-cairo-libs-fail) (credits to the authors)

The routine is part of a program called `collector`. which is linked as follows:

```
clang -o collector -g -O2 -fno-strict-aliasing collector.o common-vars.o \
collector-events.o listeners.o active_window.o \
../lib/libperfq-common.a -lPocoNet -lPocoFoundation -luiohook\
-lstdc++ -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm -lcairo -lXt -lXtst -lXinerama \
-lX11 -lpthread -lc
```

So far so good. The program works very well.

However, when I statically link the poco and uiohook libraries, the program throws a seg fault at the line indicated above.

The executable with poco and uiohook libraries statically linked is produced as follows:

```
clang -o collector -g -O2 -fno-strict-aliasing collector.o \
common-vars.o collector-events.o listeners.o active_window.o \
../lib/libperfq-common.a /home/lrleon/poco/lib/libPocoNet.a \
/home/lrleon/poco/lib/libPocoFoundation.a \
/home/lrleon/uiohook/lib/libuiohook.a -lstdc++ -lgsl -lgslcblas \
-lm -lcairo -lXt -lXtst -lXinerama -lX11 -lpthread -lc
```

With this version, I have a segfault. And after switching some dynamic libraries, watch with a debugger, I do know what is causing the error.

I guess the fact that some libraries statically chained make the call to `cairo_surface_write_to_png()` fails. But I have no idea why.

Any idea? Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you check to make sure `surface` is a valid pointer?

Comment: Yes! It is valid in the sense that it is not NULL and it points to a readable address. More about its validity I'm unable to say because I do not know cairo. However, I remark that this code works perfectly when all the libraries are dynamically linked

Comment: Are you sure that the program has write access to a file file_name and this file isn't opened in another application?

Comment: Yes I am. I verified that

Comment: Can you add a backtrace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did just patch a crash on linux due to xcb in the 2.1 branch.  That may fix your issue when 2.1.1.  I would recommend trying 2.0 which does not contain xcb to see if that fixes your problem.