# Get RGB values from cairo surface object

Tags: c++, rgb, cairo

Given code like this:

```
surface = cairo_xlib_surface_create(disp, root, DefaultVisual(disp, scr),
                                                DisplayWidth(disp, scr),
                                                DisplayHeight(disp, scr));
```

It is not clear to me how I am going to be able to access the surface object RGB values.

Does anyone have an idea?

```
unsigned char *data = cairo_image_surface_get_data(surface);
int stride = cairo_image_surface_get_stride(surface);
```

I tried to use the above code to loop through the unsigned char, but that does not work.

Answer (score 1):

From the variable name `root`, I guess you are trying to take a screenshot.

What `cairo_xlib_surface_create` gives you is an X11 drawable as a cairo surface: The actual surface data lives on the X11 server and you can just draw there.

What you apparently are looking for: An image surface. This is some block of memory in your program that contains pixel data.

Perhaps something like the following is what you are looking for?

```
cairo_surface_t *x11_surface = cairo_xlib_surface_create(disp, root,
                DefaultVisual(disp, scr), DisplayWidth(disp, scr),
                DisplayHeight(disp, scr));
cairo_surface_t *image_surface = cairo_surface_create_similar_image(x11_surface,
                 CAIRO_FORMAT_RGB24, DisplayWidth(disp, scr),
                 DisplayHeight(disp, scr));

cairo_t *cr = cairo_create(image_surface);
cairo_set_source_surface(cr, x11_surface, 0, 0);
cairo_paint(cr);
cairo_destroy(cr);
cairo_surface_destroy(x11_surface);

unsigned char *data = cairo_image_surface_get_data(image_surface);
/* Do something with data */
cairo_surface_destroy(image_surface);
```

Additional pointer: [Making a screenshot using Xlib and Cairo libs [fail]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15507788/making-a-screenshot-using-xlib-and-cairo-libs-fail)

Edit: To just take a screenshot around some given position `x` and `y`, try something like this:

```
cairo_surface_t *x11_surface = cairo_xlib_surface_create(disp, root,
                DefaultVisual(disp, scr), DisplayWidth(disp, scr),
                DisplayHeight(disp, scr));
cairo_surface_t *image_surface = cairo_surface_create_similar_image(x11_surface,
                 CAIRO_FORMAT_RGB24, 10, 10);

cairo_t *cr = cairo_create(image_surface);
cairo_set_source_surface(cr, x11_surface, -x-5, -y-5);
cairo_paint(cr);
cairo_destroy(cr);
cairo_surface_destroy(x11_surface);

unsigned char *data = cairo_image_surface_get_data(image_surface);
/* Do something with data */
cairo_surface_destroy(image_surface);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm specifically trying to calculate the average of the pixel values, indeed based on a screenshot. I do not need to draw :) To add more information, I just want to get an estimate of how dark the screen is. By being able to get the RGB values that will be possible. It would also be great if I would know where the mouse is, and then loop around the pixels around the mouse, but that's a next challenge.

Comment: XQueryPointer gives you the current mouse position: https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/window-information/XQueryPointer.html

Comment: I updated my answer to give you a hint on how to only get a 10x10 area around a given position. I hope this helps, but beware: If part of that 10x10 area is outside of the root window, you might end up with "random garbage" instead of a screenshot.